# Library to do introspection in java?

Tags: java, reflection, introspection

I need to do reflection  and introspection in my java application, but I find that `java.lang.reflect` is a little bit complex to use, and I cannot easily find solutions for what I want to do.

Do you know another library that do introspection?

Comment: Just learn to use `java.lang.reflect`: it is a learning curve but worth the pain.

Comment: You could try an [Introspector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html) - although it is designed specifically with JavaBeans in mind. In any case, this question is asking to recommend an library and is therefore off topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For introspection start with [java.beans.Introspector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html).

To get started with reflection have a look at the tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/